coin flipping question
Jay and John each flip fair coins until they obtain their first heads, respectively. Given that it takes strictly fewer flips for Jay to get his first heads than John, compute the expected number of flips Jay performed.
My solution: consider the first two flips, there are 4 conditions of which 2 are legal:
TT: next two flips
TH: illegal
HT: end for Jay
HH: illegal
So my solution is: $E(\text{Jay}) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot [E(\text{Jay}) + 1] + \frac{1}{2} \cdot 1$, which yields an answer of 2. However, the answer is $\frac{4}{3}$. So what's wrong with my solution?

Are they tossing simultaneously or turn bu turn ? If turn by turn, who tosses first ?

Yes, toss one by one. Like Jay -> John -> Jay -> John...

Here's an intuitive reason why the answer is $4/3$.
Let's frame the problem slightly differently. First, imagine that the players are flipping the coins simultaneously until at least one of them gets heads. This is the same as repeatedly rolling a $4$-sided die until we roll a $1$, $2$, or $3$. (Translation from the coin flips: HH becomes $1$, HT becomes $2$, TH becomes $3$, and TT becomes $4$.)
Let $T$ be the number of rolls that occur, i.e. there will be $T - 1$ $4$s and then a $1$, $2$, or $3$ at the end. Let $J$ be the event that the last roll is specifically a $2$. We want to compute $\mathbf{E}[T \mid J]$.
(Clarification: conditional on $J$, the number of flips Jay makes in the original framing is the number of "flip pairs" in this framing, which is why we can think in terms of flip pairs / die rolls.)
The key observation is that $T$ and $J$ are independent! This means
$$
\mathbf{E}[T \mid J] = \mathbf{E}[T] = \frac{4}{3},
$$
because clearly $T \sim \mathrm{Geometric}(3/4)$.
So why are $T$ and $J$ independent? It's because you can imagine decomposing each die roll into two stages.

Stage A: randomly choose either $\{4\}$ (w.p. $1/4$) or $\{1, 2, 3\}$ (w.p. $3/4$).
Stage B: select the roll result uniformly at random from the chosen set.

In both cases, the random choice is made independently of all previous random choices.
To determine $T$, we just need to look at the results from stage A. To determine whether $J$ occurs, we just need to look at the result of the last stage B. Specifically, conditional on any outcome $T = t$, the last stage B always causes $J$ to occur with probability $2/3$. This means $T$ and $J$ are independent.
Summary. Conditioning on $J$ is making you throw out $2/3$ of the outcomes of the process "flip until one or both players get heads". But for the purposes of the number of flips $T$, it's doing so in an unbiased way, because we're throwing out $2/3$ of the sequences for each possible sequence length. So $(T \mid J)$ has the same distribution as $T$.
The same idea works more generally: if you roll an $a$-sided die until one of $b$ "stop" rolls, conditioning on the value of the stop roll that ends the sequence doesn't affect the distribution of the sequence length.

yes, I think if we have a same starting point, i.e. simplify it to 4 states, HT, HH, TT TH, then conditioned on the event of HT. But after this you take a different approach. If I still follow the way of Markov chain, then how to solve it? I mean how to tackle the question of such state transition problem when there is a "condition on" situation? Thanks!

If you think about the infinite sequence (i.e. keep going after the game is over), the difference might be easier to spot. Your version effectively removes any outcomes where TH and HH appear in the sequence. My version only removes outcomes where TH and HH appear before the first HT—after that first HT, everything is allowed again. And the latter is the right event to condition on, because we don't care about what would happen once the game ends. This isn't a full explanation, but it's a hint that the event we're conditioning on isn't the same as removing the TH and HH outcomes altogether.

would the expected number of rolls for John then be 2? Since there are two stopping rolls (HH, TH)?

What do you mean by "for John"? If you mean "the expected number of flips John makes given that he gets less than or equal to as many as Jay", then I think the answer is still 4/3: the game ends at the same time $T$ (when either player gets heads), so we're just changing the event $J$, but in a way that makes it still independent of $T$.

Let $X$ represent the number of coin flips needed for Jay to observe the first heads, and $Y$ represent the number of coin flips needed for John to observe the first heads.  So $X$ and $Y$ are iid geometric random variables with parameter $p = 1/2$, and PMF
$$\Pr[X = x] = 2^{-x}, \quad x \in \mathbb Z^+, \\ \Pr[Y = y] = 2^{-y}, \quad y \in \mathbb Z^+.$$
Then $$\Pr[X = Y] = \sum_{x=1}^\infty \Pr[X = Y = x] = \sum_{x=1}^\infty 2^{-2x} = \frac{2^{-2}}{1 - 2^{-2}} = \frac{1}{3}.$$  By symmetry, it immediately follows that
$$\Pr[X < Y] = \Pr[X > Y] = \Pr[X = Y] = \frac{1}{3}.$$
All that remains is to compute
$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}[X \mid X < Y] &= \frac{1}{\Pr[X < Y]} \sum_{y=1}^\infty \sum_{x=2}^{y-1} x \Pr[(X = x) \cap (Y = y)] \\
&= 3 \sum_{y=2}^\infty 2^{-y} \sum_{x=1}^{y-1} x 2^{-x} \\
&= 3 \sum_{y=2}^\infty 2^{-y} 2^{1-y} (2^y - y - 1) \\
&= \frac{4}{3}.
\end{align}$$
This is the mechanical approach.  I fully acknowledge this is not a particularly elegant or insightful way to obtain the solution, but it does arrive at the correct answer.

I thought that the question meant that if John gets a head, the trial is not counted, as it is illegal and we keep skipping such trials from our calculation. If that is true, the whole thing comes down to Jay, whose expectation is based on H, TH, TTH, ... which will be sum(n/2^n) = 2. Same interpretation as OP

what is OP? @Srini

@XuShan "OP" means "Original Poster," which is referring to the person who asked the original question; in this case, you.

Thanks @heropup. Yes the answer shows similar mechanical approach, like writing it to calculate the expectation of P(X=k|X<Y). I am also wondering is there any more simple way to get the answer.

For the statement in OP, yes I have a same thought as @Srini, but not sure why it's wrong...

@XuShan A simple way to see why the answer cannot be $2$ is to note that the unconditional expectation of the number of flips is $\operatorname{E}[X] = 2$.  However, $\Pr[X = 1 \mid X < 2] = 1$, whereas $\Pr[X = 1] = 1/2$; and in general, $\Pr[X = x \mid X < y] > \Pr[X = x]$ for any fixed $y \ge 2$.  So the expectation of $X \mid X < Y$ must be less than the unconditional expectation of $X$.

I get 4/3 if I don't omit the illegal trials. For n trials, the n-1 trials can be a combination of illegals (TH, HH) or legal (TT). Which gives 3 cases for each of n-1 trials. So the expectation  is sum( 3 (n-1)/2^(2(n-1))=4/3. The factor 2 for n-1 comes from both Jay and John mattering. I guess there is a bit of confusion on the rule - to omit or include illegals for the count

Thanks @Srini, so what is 3(n-1)?

Sorry @XuShan, I think my method was wrong. I tried working through the details for posting an answer and couldn't get 4/3 with correct reasoning. I will post something if I find it
